# Blender Remesh Error in Sculpt mode. How do I decrease the polygons correctly and save the project?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, error, vertex-paint, polycount

I have a big problem.
Some time ago I asked a question about this project regarding the selection of polygons to be able to work in zones.
The problem now is another, not being an expert in polygonal sculpture, I immediately started creating my character at the maximum polygon resolution. For this reason now the file weighs too much and when I open it despite having a PC worthy of power, the 500k vertices and 900k faces I would say are really excessive.
In fact, every action that I go to perform in blender, whatever it is, needs time to load it.

In the previous question, I received an answer that my project had too many polygons and was advised to remesh my character, thus creating a low poly copy.

However, after some time I just tried to perform the remesh, perhaps inserting wrong values, I don't know, even if I took reference from the screenshot that was recommended to me.
Performing the remesh I encountered these problem.

**Problems :**

1. The whole surface is pierced, and my mesh is corrupted as shown in the figure.
2. even the color used with vertex paint is canceled and transformed into a totally reflective surface.

**Principal Questions**:

1. Am I still in time to be able to recover this project or is it to be thrown away and redone from scratch?
2. How can I consistently decrease the weight of my file without completely ruining the character?
3. Why does remesh create these holes? Can it be caused by vertex paint? How do I resolve?
   (I also tried using the Decimate modifier too, but I think it's not the exact tool).

[image]

[image]

Extra questions:

1. What would be the right technique to create a character, what are the precautions to use, especially not to stumble into certain errors.
2. Above all what are the steps that should be followed for the complete realization of a character? Such as creating a low poly copy, how to color in the right way, but above all when to do one thing instead of another.
   For these two points it is clear that a simple answer is not enough, so if you know where to send me to document me I would be grateful. (A site, a guide relating only to this). Or even some simple basic concepts that make me understand the steps to be respected.

p.s. After completing my application I was able to find several questions already asked, related to some of my extra doubts, so if you agree I will not delete these questions as maybe they can be used by someone who is looking for the same things and cannot find them. However, I have found several interesting answers for these extra questions of mine, which I will attach the links to my question. while obviously higher priority will have to be given to questions concerning my project. However, opinions, reflections and advice are always welcome.
For example this question, yes, can answer some of my doubts and I also found a video on how to paint in layers. [Paint high-poly mesh and then bake for low-poly, OR just paint low-poly with normal-map applied?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155512/paint-high-poly-mesh-and-then-bake-for-low-poly-or-just-paint-low-poly-with-nor?rq=1)
But I think I need a specific answer to this question because I can't work on this project anymore. I want to resolve my fault.

While that other question has managed to answer some of the polygon sculpture questions about how it's best and what it's best to sculpt a certain way for.
[What is the importance of low poly vs high poly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30802/what-is-the-importance-of-low-poly-vs-high-poly?rq=1)

-I tried to upload the file but it weighs 90mb, and the maximum is 30mb. how do i compress the file to upload it through the exchange? or should I use something else?

**[ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Idc8Jg9wtHwQey5V7qpwuxwtw1QjEM4K/view?usp=sharing ]**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to upload the file through google drive or something like that. The admins might complain, but as long as you make sure it's accessible to anyone with the link, they'll have to understand that you don't have a choice.

BTW, I'm fairly certain I've experienced that effect before (a very detailed sculpture like yours going bonkers with remesh), so if I can see your file maybe I'll remember what I did to fix it.

Comment: @CBarr I would be grateful , I am attaching the link to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, sorry I couldn't replicate that crazy error. It happened to me once, also with a very complex mesh, but I was using a much weaker laptop and I didn't optimize the mesh before remeshing, so maybe that was it.

---

Now, there's still some hope for your character, but you will come out of this having learned a few valuable lessons.

The very first thing you have to do is **Decimate** the mesh to make it manageable. Pick the Collapse option and you can go down to 0.2 with absolutely NO loss of detail, and you can probably push it even lower.

[image]You'll lose a ridiculous amount of polygons and make blender happy!

(By the way, it's not necessarily your computer that can't handle the pressure, it's blender that isn't exactly optimized to deal with so many polygons)

Now that you can breathe easier and your vertex paint is still there, it's time to think about the future and weight your options.

**Question: Are you going to animate this? Do you need this mesh to be posed with bones?** If yes, keep reading. If you just want to make it prettier and render a still frame, never mind, you can stop, you're all set.

---

Animation works best with as few polygons as possible, and those polygons should have nice symmetrical "flow" to make it smoother and easier overall.
That's why we need to remesh.

But Blender's Remesh options (all 3 of them, Quad, Voxel and good old Smooth) are, I'm sad to say it, **rubbish...**

- **Quad** refuses to work with non-manifold meshes (you have to go around hunting down non-manifold areas in edit mode). It produces OK
  flow (if it feels like it), but is slow and non adaptive, so it'll make many
  polygons where you could do with fewer, and not enough where you really need them.
- **Voxel** can be adaptive so it doesn't make too many polygons where they're not needed but flow is just not there, and to
  reach high detail you end up with more than you started with. But
  at least it can get reasonably close to the original!
- **Smooth** is outright insane, it'll choke itself to death to achieve even minimal detail and STILL somehow manage to ruin finer things
  like earlobes. Just, no.

*Oh yeah, and they'll all kill your vertex paint! In fact, best kiss that one goodbye  anyway, it's doomed no matter what your next step is. Sorry about that.*

So that leaves you with only one sane option....

**Retopology.**
Basically, create a new mesh, snap it to the old one for reference, extrude new edges, fill it with the least number of polygons you can afford, then throw away the old mesh.
There are many retopology tutorials and even a few addons that are supposed to help you (eh, not really). It's a drag - it takes a lot of time and is indescribably boring, but the result will be a clean, symmetrical mesh that retains all the detail exactly where you need it, and not one vertex more.

[image]

When you're done you can vertex or texture paint to your heart's content, knowing that you have a mesh that can do ANYTHING you want it to.

This is my (and many people's) workflow:

- Sculpt. Go crazy, add as much detail as you want.
- Downsize it with Decimate.
- Retopologise.
- Unwrap, UV, rig, animate.

Comment: This was one of the most comprehensive answers I've received, thank you very much.
  First of all, yes I abused the smooth tool I have to be honest, being a beginner I do not know the right steps to create a character and I went a bit to sensation.
Actually I would like to animate this character and make it graphically crazy, but as far as I understand regardless of other factors, I have to develop two types of mesh, a low and a high.

Comment: Wandering around on Github I found this add-on on retopology, do you think it could help me, along with some tutorials of course? https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow
For the rest now I will try to decimate it. which I tried to do but via unsubdivide, which crashed the blender.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I used the decimator with ratio 0.1, and it dramatically decreased the polygons. do I have to do retopology? despite making the project much lighter? do you recommend it anyway? what is the threshold that divides a low poly from wanting to animate from a high poly?

Comment: @Albizz Like I wrote, it depends on your goals. 
If you just want to render a still of the face, applying the decimate modifier is enough to get things running smoothly and you don't need to waste any more time. 
But if you want to rig and move this character, then you absolutely MUST retopo it.  Without good topology the bones won't weight easily, the joints will flex weird, and you'll see render artifacts in some areas like the shoulders (where it goes from high res to low res all of a sudden).
(TO BE CONTINUED)

Comment: I understand perfectly. Is there a threshold that separates low poly from high poly? or in any case to make it possible to use it to animate it?

Comment: @Albizz As for the threshold, I don't think there's a straight answer!
It depends on your hardware - if you find it stuttering when sculpting/editing, you should probably go low poly as soon as possible and stay that way. If the computer is handling it well, there's no reason to spend the extra time with retopology, baking, re-sculpting, bump mapping and all that stuff.
If the animation is working well (no weird artifacts popping up), it just boils down to how your computer feels.

Comment: ok I understand. thank you very much. :D

Comment: @Albizz (I didn't even see your previous comments, oops!)
Indeed, if you want to animate, you'll absolutely should retopo. You can still have a lot of detail (specially with bump maps) while saving on polygons and headaches. 
Î have no idea what's the use of "unsubdivide", it takes a long time to do absolutely nothing. Weird....
I've tried retopoflow once and gave up on it. It brings very little to the table that you can't already do with just the "E" key, merge vertex ON, snap options, and shrinkwrap modifier... By all means try it, but it did nothing for me.
Good luck on your projects!

Comment: I understand, I'll try. in that case I will always come back here for other questions. lol (Y)

Comment: @Albizz That's why we're all here for!

Comment: thanks. see u next time. :D

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add that I encountered the same choppy model result from remeshing and that closing up all holes in the model solved the problem.

**This was the result using Remesh when I had forgotten to close the neck hole:**
[image]

**After closing up the neck hole the Remesh worked fine:**
[image: good]

Happy Blending!

Comment: First makes  pretty cool effect, albeit unwanted.

Comment: This answer deserves more attention. it's actually really what causes this error most of the time. THe remesh works perfectly after closing holes. Thank you