# Why is the Remesh creating holes in the mesh?

Tags: sculpting

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Voxel size is 0.005, Adaptivity is 0, fix poles and and preserve volume on

Comment: It's because the Voxel Remesh operation needs a manifold mesh. There must be no holes and the mesh must not be flat. It needs volume. Is your mesh open in direction of the head? Related question and answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218990/107598

Comment: THANKSS I forgot there were holes in the eye sockets and it works now with a grid fill TYSM